Correct way to return first element of a JS array that meets condition and mapped
Let's say we have a function that makes expensive calculation and an array of source values for which we do the calculation. We want to get a first return value of the function that is not falsy and return it.
function expensiveFunction(params) {...}

// this is how it can be achieved using ordinary for loop
let paramsCollection = ["params1", "params2" /*, ...*/];
let result;
for (let i=0; i<paramsCollection.length; i++) {
    result = expensiveFunction(paramsCollection[i]);
    if (result) {
        break;
    }
}

I'd like to do it using Array methods.
Array.find will only return the element for which function returns something.
Array.map will run expensive calculations for all elements even if first one was ok.
Array.reduce can do the job, but it will iterate over an array anyway - even if it doesn't call the expensiveFunction it feels bad..
let paramsCollection = ["params1", "params2" /*, ...*/];
let result = paramsCollection.reduce((acc, cur) => acc ? acc : expensiveFunction(cur), null);

Any idea how to make it this way but w/out drawbacks from above examples?

why can't you use like this
function expensiveFunction(params) {...}
let result = paramsCollection.find(expensiveFunction);
console.log(result);

@HariharanSubramanian It returns the parameter, not the result.

Complex oneliners may feel smart, but the next person who tries to understand what's going on might misunderstand it. A simple for loop is often more readable and therefore easier to maintain. Don't be afraid people think you don't know about array methods, just keep your for loop.

@www.admiraalit.nl Yes, but... Each time we're challenged to understand a (more) complex solution than usuall, we learn. Array.reduce is always a bit tricky for me, but each time I have a chance to use it, it is simplier and feels more natural. Like promises/defereds years ago (vs commonly used callbacks) and then observables some years later. And asking this question made me learn array iterators which feels great. Let's agree not to overcomplicate the code while also seek for new neat solutions at the same time.

Great approach. I definitely agree!

ECMAScript 2025 will include iterator helpers, which are being rolled out now, so if you have that available (like in current versions of Edge, Chrome, ...), then this would do it:
paramsCollection.values().map(expensiveFunction).find(Boolean);

Note that:

.values() returns an iterator (not an array).
.map() and .find() are not array methods, but (new) iterator methods.
As the mapping of an item happens before the find on that item, we get a result produced by expensiveFunction.
Contrary to how array methods work, the iterator's map method will only consume values as they are needed by the iterator's find method. Once the find method has found the value that is truthy, map will not consume any more values.

NB: If you only want to skip null values (but not other falsy values), then the .find call back could be x => x !== null.
Example:


function expensiveFunction(params) {
    return params == "params2" ? "hello" : "";
}

// Example
const paramsCollection = ["params1", "params2", "params3"];
const res = paramsCollection.values().map(expensiveFunction).find(Boolean);
console.log(res);




Unbelievable. What a great feature. I understood your second paragraph as: Currently, this works with array methods and in the future with iterator helpers. "ECMAScript 2025 will include iterator helpers" It was unclear, that browsers already support them. I use a non-bleeding-edge Firefox.

The .values() array method returns an iterator (not an array), so unless you have the feature available, there is no .map method on that object.

Yes, now I see it. I wasn't reading the code carefully enough.

What a great solution! Love it. Thanks. I haven't noticed those all Iterator methods until now. I wish they were widely available across all browsers by now....

You can write your own mapFind based on Array.prototype.find:


function mapFind(arr, f) {
  let result;
  
  arr.find(el => {
    let temp = f(el);
    if (temp) result = temp;
    return temp;
  });
  return result;
}

function expensiveFunction(params) {
  return params > 7 ? params * params : 0;
}
console.log(mapFind([1, 2, 3], expensiveFunction));
console.log(mapFind([7, 8, 9], expensiveFunction));




Interesting solution. Lokking this way, it would actually work with all Array methods that return immediately after condition has been met - like some and every. Sadly it doesn't make the code any shorter comparing to using the for loop in the helper function. Thanks anyway!

I'm sure I've missed something in the nuance of the question, but why can't you just use findIndex:


function expensiveFunction(param) { return param == "params2"}

let paramsCollection = ["params1", "params2", "params3"];

let index = paramsCollection.findIndex(expensiveFunction);

if(index){
  console.log(paramsCollection[index]);
}



findIndex runs a function, returning the first index that returns a non-falsey value.

The OP wants the result. You would have to call expensiveFunction again to print the expected result: console.log(expensiveFunction(paramsCollection[index])). As you can see in the first code snippet in the question, result contains the returned value result = expensiveFunction(paramsCollection[i]);.
